# css display none select div relative behind

Tags: html, css

i wanted to know if in css there is a way to inject a display none to the relative of an attribute es;

```html
<div class="classeA">
  <div class="classeB" data-userid="1234" >
             
  </div>             
</div>
```

what should i use?

```css
[data-userid="1234"] < .classeA{
    display:none !important;
}
```

what should I do?
I want class classA with display none selecting the data-userid attribute

Comment: there is no way in css to set a rule on an element based on one of it's children attribute. You should probably rework the html to have the data-userid attribute on the parent instead

Comment: You cannot navigate up the document, CSS is fundamentally a cascading structure (Hence the name)

Comment: why not .classeA>[data-userid="1234"] {
      display: none !important;
    }

Comment: i have to put classA in display none, not the userid attribute

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), although as of yet there is [no support across any browser](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

It would look something like this:

```css
.classeA:has([data-userid="1234"]){
  display:none;
}
```

Demo:

```js
$('.classeA:has([data-userid="1234"])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classeA">
  <div class="classeB" data-userid="1234">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need for `:has` since `*[data-userid="1234"].classeA` is also valid

Comment: But that does not select the previous sibling which is what OP is looking for I think

Comment: @Apolo I think OP was trying to hide elements with the `classeA` class that contained elements with the `data-userid` attribute

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work it doesn't put me the div classA display none

Comment: @natoduevolte It is not possible because there is no CSS parent selector. Once `:has()` has been implemented, it should work, but like I stated in my answer, it is not supported across any browser.